# How can i restart toggle when another button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 buttons each of them has toggle function with 2 function inside the toggle.
i have a problem that i want the toggle to be restarted if the user didn't click on the same button twice for example

if the user clicks on X first function will fires if he clicks on Y and then re-click on X the first function will fires again. but if he clicks on X first function will fires and he clicks on X again then the second function will fires.

```
$('x').toggle(
   function(){
     //something
   },
   function(){
     //something
   }
}

$('y').toggle(
   function(){
     //something
   },
   function(){
     //something
   }
}
```

please tell me your opinions and if there is a solution better than toggle ... please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.toggle`, as it won't provide you with what you need.  Make something custom instead, giving the "x" button state (and changes to the state execute your functions) which can be modified by the "y" button.